# Pra que serve um pull request?

Tags: git, versionamento

Estou trabalhando em equipe no bitbucket e gostaria de saber para que serve um pull request. Em quais ocasiões devemos usar esse recurso.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Pull request é um mecanismo onde um desenvolvedor pode gerar uma notificação que sinaliza a conclusão do desenvolvimento de uma feature qualquer. Isso permite que todos os envolvidos saibam que precisam fazer o merge do código na branch principal.
Além disso, podem ser discutidas as alterações em um fórum para possíveis aperfeiçoamentos da feature em questão.

Veja mais em https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/making-a-pull-request

Answer (score 22):

Quando você tem várias pessoas trabalhando em cima de uma mesma base de arquivos texto, o ideal é que cada pessoa tenha uma cópia do código para trabalhar. Não acredite apenas porque eu estou dizendo, tente abrir *online* um arquivo .doc compartilhado e editar ele simultaneamente com várias outras pessoas. Depois tome um banho de sal grosso.

Para organizar o trabalho em equipe, foi criado há muito tempo uma coisa chamada "controle de versão". Até hoje são populares alguns sistemas antigos, como o Source Safe da Microsoft e o SVN.

Os sistemas de controle de versão que usam git em geral têm como diferencial em relação aos sistemas mais antigos uma funcionalidade bem específica, essa chamada `pull request`. É basicamente uma forma de você dizer: acabei o meu trabalho, preciso integrá-lo no ramo principal  e eis aqui o que eu fiz. Ao utilizar essa funcionalidade, é gerado um registro no servidor (por exemplo, o *GitHub*, que é bem popular) que destaca as diferenças de código entre o ramo no qual você trabalhou e o ramo alvo da entrega. Assim fica fácil para o administrador do repositório revisar o seu trabalho. Também dá para iniciar discussões sobre trechos específicos das alterações. Por fim, o próprio git facilita a mesclagem do código.

Isso incentiva a revisão em pares e o trabalho ordenado em equipe, e no caso de projetos open source incentiva também a contribuição de por parte da comunidade.